# Find $\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{C_n^k A^n B^{k-n} n!}{(\frac{n}{2})!}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

$$
\mbox{What does}\quad
\sum_{n = 0}^{k}{k \choose n}A^{n}B^{k - n}\,{n! \over \left(n/2\right)!}\quad
\mbox{converge to ?}
$$

I know it converges (I have found an upper bound for it but I can't work out what it converges to?

I am using the definition: $\left(n/2\right)!=\Gamma\left(n/2 + 1\right)$.

Comment: What is $C_n^k$ here?

Comment: @vonbrand the binomial coefficient: $C_n^k=\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}$

Comment: Use $\large{k \choose n}$ instead of $\large C_{n}^{k}$.

Comment: do you mean as $k \to \infty$?